# Explain MatchConfidence internal working in matching rule

Tags: automation

Please explain how MatchConfidence is calculated in matching rule

Answer (score 1):

As per Salesforce docs:

> The exact matching method looks for strings that exactly match a
> pattern. If you’re using international data, we recommend using the
> exact matching method with your matching rules. You can use the exact
> matching method for almost any field, including custom fields.
>
> The
> fuzzy matching methods look for strings that approximately match a
> pattern. Specific fuzzy matching methods are available for commonly
> used standard fields on accounts, contacts, and leads.

[Matching Methods Used in Matching Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_matching_methods.htm&type=5)